# HOW TO CREATE MULTIPLE RECORDS BASED ON THE NUMBER OF DAY CHOSEN?

Tags: apex, trigger

As you can see in the picture below, I created a check box named "Long-term work". It will pop up a Start Date and End Date for users to insert in, for example if the start date is June 25 and the end date is June 30(which's 6 days), I want SF to create 6 records for each days for me. how can I do that by using TRIGGER ? If possible, hope can hear any suggestion from everyone.
[image]

```
trigger FCRM_LogWorkTrigger on Log_Work__c (before insert, before update) {
    integer numberOfDays;
    List<Log_Work__c> listLogWork =  new List<Log_Work__c>();
    if (trigger.isBefore && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)) {
        for (Log_Work__c test : trigger.new) {
            if (test.Period__c == true) {
                Date startDate = test.From__c;
                Date endDate = test.To__c;
                numberOfDays = startDate.daysBetween(endDate) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    system.debug('Number of days ===>' +numberOfDays);
    for(integer i=0; i < numberOfDays; i++) {
        Log_Work__c newAccount = new Log_Work__c();
        newAccount.Name = 'Test Acc' +i;
        listLogWork.Add(newAccount);
    }
    insert listLogWork;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try the same logic in after insert/Update trigger instead of before trigger.

Doing any kind of dml operation for same object is not suggested to do in the before trigger, it may lead to recursion and eventually trigger will fail.

In before trigger we perform dml operation for other objects. If you want to perform dml operation on the same object which fired the triggered should be done in after trigger.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, I wonder if I don't want to create records on weekends, how can I do that in the code ?

Comment: @LêQuangAnh Using the date class in apex Find out current day, and if the day fall on weekend just skip the logic for execution.